# React native svg arc path

Tags: react-native, svg

I create arc in react native svg like in image below

[image: My arc]

code for arc:

```
 <Path
    d="M 50 8 A 1 1 0 0 1 50 92"
    fill="skyblue"
    stroke="blue"
    strokeWidth="15"
  />
```

but how I can do something like this on second image. To have 2 arcs with center hole

[image: Arc 2]

Comment: Do you have to use a path? Or can you use circles instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must stick with the path, here's an option that uses strokes, and a clipping path (all the exact same path).

```html
<svg width="140" height="110" viewbox="0 -5 140 110" style="background:#efefef">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="my-clip">
      <path
        d="M 50 8 A 1 1 0 0 1 50 92"
      />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <path
    clip-path="url(#my-clip)"
    d="M 50 8 A 1 1 0 0 1 50 92"
    fill="none"
    stroke="skyblue"
    stroke-width="55"
  />
  <path
    d="M 50 8 A 1 1 0 0 1 50 92"
    fill="none"
    stroke="blue"
    stroke-width="15"
  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it. Can you still explain how to get that second arc on the left?